# RG flow of coupled two scalar fields

Tags: field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

Considering an action in $1\le d<4$ dimensions that including deformation of a Gaussian action:
$$S=S_0+\int d^dx[g_1 \mu^{\epsilon_1}\cdot\phi_1^4(x)+g_2 \mu^{\epsilon_2}\cdot\phi_2^4(x)+g_3\mu^{\frac{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2}{2}}\phi_1^2(x)\phi_2^2(x)] $$
when the gaussian part is given by:
$$S_0=\int d^dx_1\int d^dx_2\left[\frac{\phi_1(x_1)\phi_1(x_2)}{|x_1-x_2|^{2(d-\Delta_1)}}+\frac{\phi_2(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)}{|x_1-x_2|^{2(d-\Delta_2)}}\right]$$
when $\Delta_i=\frac{d-\epsilon_i}{4}$ and $\epsilon_i\ll 1$,
$\mu$ is floating cutoff scale and $g_i$ are dimensionless couplings.

I want to find the 1-loop beta function for each coupling $g_i$ up to order $\epsilon_i$ I tried to find 1-loop correction for each possible 4 point function one for $\phi_1^4$ one for $\phi_2^4$ and one for $\phi_1^2\phi_2^2$. but each of the renormalized couplings is dependent on other couplings which don`t allow me to express the beta function for each explicitly as values of the couplings $g_i$ but instead, I get that for example beta function of $g_1$, $\beta(g_1)$ is depended on $\beta(g_3)$
I would like to know how to overcome this problem.